# Can I change Selenium ChromeDriver name?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I launch Selenium's web driver (Chromedriver), a console window (chromedriver.exe) runs and it opens chrome.

I need to know how i can change name chromedriver.exe?

It is a possible? I am using C#.

Comment: Why do you want to change chromedriver name?

Comment: Because i open many driver and i can't close special driver.

Comment: @OnurŞahin Was just curious to know your requirement because I have certain solutions for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You cannot change the driver name.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can change the name of the driver, but then you also have to update the `System.getProperty("path/to/renamed_driver_executable")` to make the renamed driver work.